# Lightcore IoC is returning the same instance when it should give a new one

Tags: .net, ioc-container

I have the following code using the lightcore IoC container.
But it fails with "NUnit.Framework.AssertionException:   Contained objects are equal" which indicates that the objects that should be transient, are not.

Is this a bug in lightcore, or am I doing it wrong? My German isn't good enough to read the documentation.

```
[Test]
public void JellybeanDispenserHasNewInstanceEachTimeWithDefault()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.DefaultControlledBy<TransientLifecycle>();
    builder.Register<IJellybeanDispenser, VanillaJellybeanDispenser>();
    builder.Register<SweetVendingMachine>().ControlledBy<TransientLifecycle>();
    builder.Register<SweetShop>();

    IContainer container = builder.Build();
    SweetShop sweetShop = container.Resolve<SweetShop>();
    SweetShop sweetShop2 = container.Resolve<SweetShop>();

    Assert.IsFalse(ReferenceEquals(sweetShop, sweetShop2), "Root objects are equal");
    Assert.IsFalse(ReferenceEquals(sweetShop.SweetVendingMachine, sweetShop2.SweetVendingMachine), "Contained objects are equal");
    Assert.IsFalse(ReferenceEquals(sweetShop.SweetVendingMachine.JellybeanDispenser, sweetShop2.SweetVendingMachine.JellybeanDispenser), "services are equal");
}
```

Comment: Looks like a bug to me if you read the documentation. Objects you resolve directly are transient, properties of these objects appear not to be...

Comment: Maybe you can contact the author directly: http://www.peterbucher.ch/kontakt.aspx. I've never worked with LightCore so I can't help you any further.

Answer (score 1):

@Anthony
Thanks for reporting the issue, that helps me a alot!

The bug should be fixed. Bugfix and integration test are commited to the official svn repository at: http://lightcore.ch/download.aspx

**Update**:
LightCore 1.4 is now available on the mentioned site above, the **bug is fixed** in this release,

Comment: Thanks! I have moved the "builder.DefaultControlledBy" line to before the registrations, since I think this makes a difference. Does it?

Comment: Yes, i use deferred execution of the registration code, but the used variable for "DefaultLifecycle, e.g. Singleton" is captured right on the registration itself.

That means, all statements after a new line of "DefaultControlledBy" use that lifecycle.

Thanks for your attention, i will add a comment in the documentation on this.